# Creating two Nuget packages with dependency

Tags: c#, build, nuget, nuget-package

I have been looking a while before asking here. Hoping that others have solved this problem.

I have trouble creating nuget packages from two different projects in the same solution. One project is dependent on another, and when I try to create a pre-release version the nuget package from the depending project depends on the released package and not the pre-released one.

Here is the setup:

```
Solution
    Project A
        a.nuspec
    Project B
        b.nuspec
```

Where *project B* has a internal reference to *project A*.
When I run the command

```
nuget pack b.nuspec -IncludeReferencedProjects -Properties Configuration=Release -version 8.1.0-beta0003
```

I get a resulting nupkg from **b.nuspec** looks like this:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>project b</id>
        <version>8.1.0-beta0000</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency id="project a" version="8.1.0.0" />
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

The resulting nupkg from **a.nuspec**:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>project a</id>
        <version>8.1.0-beta0000</version>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

As you can see project b does not get a pre-release dependency on project a.

Why is this happening?

What is a good setup for building nuget packages with internal referenced dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue here, but found the explanation in this issue:
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1795

> The $version$ token is always a replacement from the assembly version that
>   was built. In specifying the -Version switch, you are overriding the
>   content of the version element and not providing a new value for the
>   $version$ token.

From this thread too, the solution would be to add this to your command line:

```
-Properties "PackageVersion=1.0.0-beta1"
```

And then in your .nuspec file, using `$PackageVersion$` everywhere instead of $version$

Didn't test it though, I don't know yet how to get my version number for my case, but I hope it can help.